# Scala - Chaining Futures Try blocks?

Tags: scala, exception, future

Is it possible to chain scala.util.Try and scala.concurrent.Future? They both effectively provide the same monadic interface, but attempting to chain them results in a compile error.

For example. Given the two signatures below

```
def someFuture:Future[String] = ???
def processResult(value:String):Try[String] = ???
```

is it possible to do something like the following?

```
val result = for( a <- someFuture; b <- processResult( a ) ) yield b;
result.map { /* Success Block */ } recover { /* Failure Block */ }
```

This obviously results in a compile error, because Future and Try are unable to be flatMapp'ed together.

It would however be a nice feature to be able to chain them - is this at all possible? Or do I need to combine them into a Future[Try[String]]?

(In particular, I'm interested in having a single 'recover' block to catch exceptions in either the future *or* the try).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When faced with a problem like this, where you want to use differing types in a for comprehension, one solution can be to try and select one of the types and map the other type to it.  For your situation, given the unique properties (async) of futures, I would select `Future` as the lowest common denominator and map the `Try` to the `Future`.  You can simply do that like this:

```
val result = for{
  a <- someFuture
  b <- tryToFuture(processResult(a)) 
}  yield b
result.map { /* Success Block */ } recover { /* Failure Block */ }

def tryToFuture[T](t:Try[T]):Future[T] = {
  t match{
    case Success(s) => Future.successful(s)
    case Failure(ex) => Future.failed(ex)
  }
}
```

Now if you found this to be a very common situation and you did not like constantly having to add in the explicit conversion, I suppose you could define the `tryToFuture` method as implicit on some helper object and import it where needed like this:

```
object FutureHelpers{
  implicit def tryToFuture[T](t:Try[T]):Future[T] = {
    t match{
      case Success(s) => Future.successful(s)
      case Failure(ex) => Future.failed(ex)
    }
  }
}

import FutureHelpers._
val result = for{
  a <- someFuture
  b <- processResult(a) 
}  yield b
result.map { /* Success Block */ } recover { /* Failure Block */ }
```

Just remember that calling `Future.success` and `Future.failed` has an impact on whatever `ExecutionContext` is in scope in that it will submit another task to it under the hood.

**EDIT**

As Viktor pointed out in the comments, the process of converting a `Try` to a`Future` is even easier if you just use `Future.fromTry` like in the updated example from below:

```
val result = for{
  a <- someFuture
  b <- Future.fromTry(processResult(a)) 
}  yield b
result.map { /* Success Block */ } recover { /* Failure Block */ }
```

This is probably your best bet versus doing stuff with implicits or rolling your own conversion logic.

Comment: there is currently a [discussion on scala-user](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/Mu4_lZAWxz0/discussion) about this exact problem of converting a `Try` to a `Future`. Maybe an helper like this should be included in the standard library somewhere.

Comment: @ViktorKlang, yes you are right. I updated my answer to include that approach. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
val result = for( a <- someFuture) yield for( b <- processResult( a ) ) yield b;
```

Although it does not look neat.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the problem is old but currently you can:

```
  implicit def tryToFuture[T](t:Try[T]):Future[T] = Promise.fromTry(t).future
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  implicit def convFuture[T](ft: Future[Try[T]]): Future[T] =
ft.flatMap {
  _ match {
    case Success(s) => Future.successful(s)
    case Failure(f) => Future.failed(f)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also

```
Future.fromTry(Try { ... })
```

So you could do

```
 val result = for {
   a <- someFuture
   b <- Future.fromTry(processResult(a)) 
 } yield b;
```